# How to asynchronously load changes from an update to a database in Angular Frontend

Tags: angular, mongodb, asynchronous, rxjs

So I have a frontend component which displays a list of Skill objects. I load the data in on my OnInit method retrieving the list from my MongoDB database.

*skill-feedback.component.ts*

```
public skills$!: Observable<Skill[]>;
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.skills$ = this.skillService.getSkillsObservable();
}
```

*skill.service.ts*

```
  getSkillsObservable(): Observable<Skill[]> {
       return this.http.get<Skill[]>('http://localhost:3000/api/skills');
    }
```

This is how I display the list in my html file, I subscribe to the observable using an asnyc pipe

*skill-feedback.component.html*

```
 <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let skill of skills$ | async">
            {{skill.skillName}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

But when I add a new skill to my data using an input-form component. The skills do not update asynchronously unless I refresh the page.
*input-form.component.ts*

```
 onSubmit() {
      this.skillService.addSkill(this.skill);
}
```

I am not that familiar with rxJS so I am unsure of the best approach to fix this issue. My webpage looks like this:
[image]
So when I hit the submit button to add a new skill I want the list below to be updated automatically. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you show what exactly `addSkill` method does?

Comment: @MichałTkaczyk 
  skill = new Skill("","", "", "", "", "", false, this.user, [],0);

    this.skillService.getSkills().then(skillMongoData => {
      this.skillData = skillMongoData;
      let id = (this.skillData.length + 1); 
      this.skill.skillId =  id.toString();
      this.skillService.addSkill(this.skill);
}

Comment: I meant `addSkill` method from your `SkillService`. I'd suggest to modify your `skills$` variable, but I need to see what is done inside this method to help, and please add it as a code to your question :)

Comment: Sorry this is the one

  async addSkill(newSkill: any) {
        var headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        const promise = await this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/skill', newSkill, { headers: headers }).subscribe(data => { console.log(data) });
        return promise;
    }

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use a different technology like Firebase with onSnapshotCjange().
You could also use a socketio instance to notify users connected to update data.
And third, ylu could use GraphQL subscriptions to updare data whenever data changes.

Answer (score 0):

this.skills$  is a one off cold observable, not a continuous hot stream. That's it only fire once with async pipe

You have to retrigger it in order to get the latest skills with some pattern like below

```
this.skill$=new BehaviorSubject(null)
this.getSkill=()=>this.http.get(...).subscribe(data=>this.skill$.next(data));

addSkill(....).subscribe(()=>this.getSkill())
```